# Searching then adding record in Redis using Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

I may be over tired but for the life of me I cannot understand why the following is not working. I am trying to search if a string exists and if it does not, add it to a redis database

```
options = options || {};
var counter = 1,
    client  = redis.getClient();
options.name = options.name || '';
if (_.isEmpty(options.name)) {
    return callback('Cannot add name. No name supplied');
} else {
    options.name = options.name.trim();
}
client.get('mySavedKeys' + options.name, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {return callback(err); }
    if (!_.isNull(data)) {
        console.log('Name found', options.name);
        return callback(null, data);
    } else {
        counter += 1;
        console.log('Name not found', options.name);
        console.log('ID', counter)
        client2.set('mySavedKeys' + options.name, counter, function (err) {
            if (err) {return callback(err); }
            console.log('Added', options.name);
            return callback(null, counter);
        });
    }
});
```

If I run an array of names to add using async.each then it seems to run all the 'get' functions and then run the 'set' function so I am getting duplicate insertions.
I'm sure the answer is obvious but I cannot see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use async.eachSeries you would insure that the get/set happen atomically rather than all gets running in parallel.